# GET parametrs and .htaccess - strange URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with .htaccess rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*)$ /other-app/application/$2&THEME=$1 [L]
```

I need URL:

```
localhost:8443/other-app/application/nice-url-theme/index.php
localhost:8443/other-app/application/nice-url-theme/edit.php?edit&EDIT_ID=XX
localhost:8443/other-app/application/nice-url-theme/brow.php
localhost:8443/other-app/application/nice-url-theme/brow.phpPARAM1=XX&PARAM2=YY
```

If I get URL

```
localhost:8443/other-app/application/nice-url-theme/edit.php?edit&EDIT_ID=XX
```

It show error **404: other-app/application/edit.php&THEME=nice-url-theme not found.**

Where is it problem in parametr star? Why it can't take GET parametrs?

Comment: Is this `.htaccess` inside `other-app/application/` directory?

Comment: Yes, It's right directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/(.*)$ /other-app/application/$2?THEME=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

- `?` instead of `&` for correctly forming query string
- `QSA` for preserving existing query string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working but I need other parametrs (QSA) in front. Example edit.php?edit&EDIT_ID=5&THEME=..... Can you help me?

Comment: yes, but now query string look like THEME=XX&edit&EDIT_ID=50 and I need move parametr THEME to end of query string.

Comment: Order of parameters in a query string doesn't matter esp. when it is an internal rewrite. Your php file will just use `$_GET['THEME']` and it will be available.

Comment: However if you really want to keep `THEME` parameter in the end for some reason then use: `RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/(.*)$ /other-app/application/$2?%{QUERY_STRING}&THEME=$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: yes, that's true but I use private CMS and there is function on cut query string for action edit (StrTok($QUERY_STRING, '&')). OK I try to rewrite our system. Thank you very much for your help.